# Is there an Android Testing Service I can use to give me real debug information from a device?

Tags: android

I need test my Android app on a Motorola Cliq but don't have one. Is there a testing service that will let me make a debug connection to that device so I can run some tests and find out where the code is failing. Video connections won't tell me that.

Comment: The android SDK contains an emulator, does your app fail in that?

Answer (score 3):

I have only heard of two choices that let you test on physical units, [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com) and [Device Anywhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/). It'll cost money obviously, but it's a great concept if you really need to test your Application.

As for video connections not telling you anything.. what else can you do? I mean, you either have it in hand, or out of hand heh. I'd write some wrappers and push debug information into the App itself, so Video can be more useful.