# Suggested method for testing android apps

Tags: android, testing

I'm about ready to release 6 apps on the Google Play market, and a guy at work brought in a new phone that was running a version of android that the manifest file stated was supported and it didn't work as expected even though it did work on the emulator. This brought up the question of

> Short of buying every device, how can we ensure that our apps will work on all devices that run the versions of android that the manifest file says it supports?

Is there a suggested way to do this? The combinations of different screen sizes, densities, and android versions can make development for android a real pain.

Edit:

The part that "didn't work as expected" was some of the javascript calls. Especially calls like window.width and window.height, the width was reported as the height and the height was reported as the width on 2.3.4, but not 2.1, or 3+. Another issue, also with 2.3.4 and javascript was the window.open(url, target) call would only call the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` on my `WebViewClient` the first time for each target rather than every time. Again, it worked with 2.1 and 3+.

Currently, I test on devices running 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 4.0.3, and 4.0.4. I also test on emulators running 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, and 4.1 with various screen sizes and densities. The javascript bugs are not present on the 2.3.3 or any of the other emulators, which is why I would rather test on devices, they give me a more accurate feel of what the user will run into

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201511/how-to-be-sure-that-android-application-will-work-on-every-device) helps.

Comment: Outside of testing with multiple emulator AVDs, or running a limited beta to users to get more specific feedback, all you can do is follow best practices for supporting multiple screens, and hope for the best. As far as "didn't work as expected", you should probably be more specific on that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, [here is a presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/95607604/Pocket-Gems-Android-QA-Process) that discusses how to potentially address the problem. This is obviously not easy, but [here is another similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852248/is-there-an-android-testing-service-i-can-use-to-give-me-real-debug-information).

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly what you exactly mean by "didn't work as expected" but this can help you quite a lot:

In my opinion, the best way to test your Android application is to install a Jenkins Continuous Integration Server, and use the Android Emulator plugin to execute the application on your application builds on emulators with various settings (screen density, OS version, etc.). The plugin can take automatically screenshots so you can see afterwards how your application looks on each configuration. Also, builds and testing can be trigerred daily, or each time you commit some code on your SCM (Git, SVN, you name it).

The configuration of the plugin is detailed on the official page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin